# Proguard not letting me export apk

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I have  a problem when I'm trying to export my project in eclipse. 
While trying to create the apk gives me this error. 
What could cause this?

```
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\android\tools\proguard\bin\X\proguard\dump.txt (The system cannot find the path specified) 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source) 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at proguard.FileWordReader.<init> FileWordReader.java:46) 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(ConfigurationParser.java: 196)
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:105) 
[2011-11-06 17:29:50 - Project- X]      at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:491)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed the steps described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) to configure proguard and run it in an Eclipse or Ant build ?

Because you have here an exception generated because the file "dump.txt" wasn't found, and it's supposed to be when you run proguard...

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did follow that one and it said that those files should be automatically generated when building the apk. But it didn't. I dod however find some problems about spaces in the project name. So I change the project name and path so it didn't have any spaces. And I also specified the exact path to proguard.cfg which I shouldn't have to since I hadn't moved it. After all this it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also comes when eclipse is not able to read the progaurd file from the sdk directory.

For me dump.txt file was present in my project, still eclipse was not able to read it.

I fixed this by changing the sdk path in the project.properties file

from

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

to

```
progaurd.config=D:\Backup\Desktops\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

where my sdk was located.